# Test Flight - Local Network permission, NSBonjourServices error in TestFlight build

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios14, mdns

For iOS14  we are supposed to get the local network permission from the user. The app works fine if I run directly on the device or export it as an Enterprise application. If I upload the same app to ****Test flight** I am getting the following error.**

> App Info.plist(NSBonjourServices) does not allow
> '_xxx-xxx-config._tcp.' for (Lhoapp)

What is this error? How to fix this?

In **Info.plist** I have added the following services used in app:

```
<key>NSBonjourServices</key>
    <array>
        <string>_xxx-xxx-config._tcp</string>
        <string>_iri._tcp</string>
    </array>
```

I am getting the following errors in the log

> ["NSNetServicesErrorDomain": 10, "NSNetServicesErrorCode": -72008]

I have enabled the Local network permission under privacy for the app

Comment: can you share your info.plist as XML format ?

Comment: @zeytin I have updated the question with the requested plist content

Comment: @zeytin can you please share any resources or documents for the format given by Apple?

Comment: i think you skipped the NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription rather than format, i dropped an answer below, pls check out

Comment: @zeytin i have already added the NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nslocalnetworkusagedescription?language=objc) indicates that for `NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription`

> Any app that uses the local network, directly or indirectly, should include this description. This includes apps that use Bonjour and services implemented with Bonjour, as well as direct unicast or multicast connections to local hosts.

Then you need to add `NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription` And your plist should be like this, of course change your app name and tcp.

```
<key>NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription</key>
<string>Exchange data with nearby devices running the Yourapp.</string>
<key>NSBonjourServices</key>
<array>
    <string>_yourApp._tcp</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding both of NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription and
NSBonjourServices keys in Infos.plist is the correct solution for me. This is required since iOS 14 and it makes NSNetServices finding services.
Thank a lot for this information.